# Python: Copy context (contextvars.Context) to a separate thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-contextvars

As for now, I've found a lot of examples on how contextvars module behaves with asyncio, but none on how one behaves with threads (asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor, threading.Thread, and so on).

My question is, how can I pass context to a separate thread? Below you can see a code snippet that does not work (python 3.9.8).

```
import typing
import asyncio
import contextvars
import concurrent.futures


class CustomThreadPoolExecutor(concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor):
    def submit(
        self,
        function: typing.Callable,
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ) -> concurrent.futures.Future:
        context = contextvars.copy_context()
        return super().submit(
            context.run,
            functools.partial(function, *args, **kwargs)
        )


def function():
    print(var.get())


async def main():
    await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, function)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    var = contextvars.ContextVar('variable')
    var.set('Message.')

    asyncio.get_event_loop().set_default_executor(CustomThreadPoolExecutor)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use wrapper function that takes `copy_context.items()`, set them and call your function. `functools.partial` will help you to create wrapped function for passing to `run_in_executor`. This is working test for my decorators:

```py
def test_run_in_thread_pool_executor():
    def init(func, ctx_vars, *args, **kwargs):
        for var, value in ctx_vars:
            var.set(value)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    @async_add_headers('streaming')
    async def wrapper(f):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
        executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
        return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, functools.partial(init, f, ctx.items()))

    @add_headers('client')
    def foo():
        assert caller_context_var.get() == 'streaming'

    async def main_test():
        await wrapper(foo)

    asyncio.run(main_test())
```

Here `add_headers` and `async_add_headers` change some contextvars in order of calling functions. `caller_context_var.get()` would be equal to `'client'` without `init` function.

Unfortunately it works only for `ThreadPoolExecutor` and doesn't for `ProcessPoolExecutor` because Context objects are not picklable. Check relative [PEP 567 section](https://peps.python.org/pep-0567/#making-context-objects-picklable). There are also example with executor:

```py
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
current_context = contextvars.copy_context()

executor.submit(current_context.run, some_function)
```